# SWFLoader vertical scrolling

Tags: apache-flex, scrollbar, swfloader

I have flash movie with 5 frames in swfloader. Is there any chances to scroll between frames like documents?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this scenario:
1. Load the swf file as an stream using a `URLStream` object.
2. Load multiple instances of that swf using a `Loader` object (`Loader.loadBytes`).
(the content object of the latter loader is a `MovieClip` instance.)
4. Use these MovieClips as pages of a document. Send each MovieClip to a specific frame.
5. Place these MovieClips in a scrollable `VGroup` container.
that's done!

There is also an open source project by devaldi called "[Flex Paper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/)" which may be helpful.

One more thing: [ForcibleLoader](http://www.libspark.org/svn/as3/ForcibleLoader/src/org/libspark/utils/ForcibleLoader.as) is a great library which makes your code compatible with old AVM1 files.